# InstallShield silent response file template

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, silent-installer

I'm trying to automate the creation of a response file from a template for different application versions by replacing all parameters with placeholders like `@placeholder@` and replacing them by script.

So I'm wondering what are these keys **2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F** in the response file. From my inspections these keys are different between different install packages of the same product, but they will be the same for a specific installer file.

Is there any way to get this value in cmd before I'm executing the installation file? Any help will be appreciated.

Here is one of my response files:

```
[InstallShield Silent]
Version=v7.00
File=Response File
[File Transfer]
OverwrittenReadOnly=NoToAll
[{2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-DlgOrder]
Dlg0={2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdWelcome-0
Count=6
Dlg1={2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-AskOptions-0
Dlg2={2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdAskDestPath-0
Dlg3={2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdAskDestPath-1
Dlg4={2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdStartCopy-0
Dlg5={2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdFinish-0
[{2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdWelcome-0]
Result=1
[{2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-AskOptions-0]
Result=1
Sel-0=1
[{2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdAskDestPath-0]
szDir=@INSTALLDIR@
Result=1
[{2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdAskDestPath-1]
szDir=@INSTALLDIR@
Result=1
[{2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdStartCopy-0]
Result=1
[{2DB45742-C30B-4262-A809-C16BB5DC585F}-SdFinish-0]
Result=1
bOpt1=0
bOpt2=0
```

Thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

This is Product GUID, you can find it in your InstallShield project settings.

Comment: After digging on web, seems that this value is GUID of the application for the uninstall shield so if in my case install-shield only delivers/replaces files (patch) it's doesn't matter what I'm gong to put there it might be any string if I'm placing them in the correct folder were my initial application installation is installed. Right?